# Periodic Share Access Fails

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, file-sharing

We have a file server running Windows Server 2012 R2.
It also hosts various VMs.

The server has 2 NIC cards set up in a Team (Switch Independent, Dynamic, None) setup. And the Hyper-V vEthernet runs off the team too.

Periodically, on many clients (7, 8.1 and 10), suddenly I am not able to access any of the server shares.

Ping, works.
DNS resolves to the correct IP.
Access to the VMs is NOT affected

Cannot RDP.
Cannot access file shares.
Cannot connect directly via IP either

Randomly starts working again after a short period of time. I am not sure even where to start looking for the issue.

What I have tried:
Disabling IPv6,
Disabling NetBIOS,
Checking services for restart events,
Checking Event Logs (but not quite sure what to look for)

I need help.

Comment: I'm of the opinion that a Hyper-V host should be used strictly as a Hyper-V host. My suggestion would be to create a virtual machine to be used as a file server and move your Shares and data to this VM.

Comment: We have not had a problem for 2 years. Something changed. I am just trying to find the issue.